# Pass context to angular component selector using ng-content

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular components, where I'm projecting one component into another via content. For example:

`app-component-a-controls` is projected into `app-component-a`. `app-component-a` draws several `app-component-a-controls` via `*ngFor`.

`app-component-a` HTML:

```
<app-component-a>
   <app-component-a-controls>
     <button (click)="log(record)">Click Me!</button>
   </app-component-a-controls>
</app-component-a>
```

`app-component-a-controls` HTML:

```
<... *ngFor="...">
   <ng-content select="app-component-a-controls"></ng-content>
</...>
```

I need somehow to access items outside, for example when I click button `Click Me!`, I need to get ngFor corresponding item as parameter called `record`. Something like the following:

```
<app-component-a>
   <app-component-a-controls let-record>
      <button (click)="log(record)">Click Me!</button>
   </app-component-a-controls>
</app-component-a>
```

Any ideas, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your `button` through an `@Input()` of `<app-component-a-controls>` as a `TemplateRef`.

So you app component template would look something like this....

#### app.component.html

```html
<app-component-a>
  <app-component-a-controls [buttonTemplate]="buttonTemplateExample"></app-component-a-controls>
  <ng-template let-record="record" #buttonTemplateExample>
    <button (click)="log(record)">Click Me!</button>
  </ng-template>
</app-component-a>
```

Notice the `let-record="record"` on the `ng-template` which we declare as a template variable that will be resolved when we render the template in the `app-component-a-controls` component.

Then in your `app-component-a-controls` template render the button template using `ng-container` with `[ngTemplateOutlet]` and then use `[ngTemplateOutletContext]` to pass a "record" value to our template...

#### app-component-a-controls.component.html

```html
<div *ngFor="let control of controls">
  {{ control.label }}
  <ng-container 
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="buttonTemplate"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ record: control.record }">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

#### app-component-a-controls.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a-controls',
  templateUrl: './component-a-controls.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-a-controls.component.css'],
})
export class ComponentAControlsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public buttonTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  public controls: any[] = [
    {
      label: 'ControlA',
      record: 'This is the value for Control A',
    },
    {
      label: 'ControlB',
      record: 'This is the value for Control B',
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I put together a working stackblitz of this approach...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e3wjne